# Receive paramter with cURL PHP using XMLHTTP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, curl, xmlhttprequest

My program is using a JS XMLHTTP request to a PHP file with cURL code to retrieve the contents of another page. I'm calling a PHP file in order to avoid a cross-origin-request error by the browser. I need to send my PHP file a JS variable, `psswd`, so it can use it when executing a cURL request.

I'm using the following JavaScript code to get the contents of another page:

```
var psswd = "test";
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
else{ xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
xmlhttp.open("POST", "parsefeed.php?psswd=" + psswd, false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

My cURL PHP script where i need to use this variable is:

```
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url ,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT        => $cert_file ,
    CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD  => $< * VARIABLE GOES HERE * >,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch , $options); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
```

I've tried using `$_POST['psswd']` and checking if anything is even posted, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how I can verify the variable is being passed?

Comment: Use `jQuery` for crossbrowser compatible ajax calls.

Comment: Move your `?psswd=" + psswd` to within of `send` - `xmlhttp.send("psswd=" + psswd)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a valid POST request which is accessable through PHP you have to specify a header and pass your data in the `.send()` method:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "parsefeed.php", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("psswd=" + psswd);
```

But it would be a lot more secure and easier to use [jQuerys ajax abilities](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I tried looking at jQuery ajax but i couldn't find anything for sending an SSL certificate to access the website's content. Why would jQuery be more secure? Does this method not encrypt the information that is being sent? What's the difference.

Comment: Well do you want to send a cert file from the client with javascript (ajax) to the server? Why?

Comment: So my javascript asks a user for the password and just delegates it to my php script. My php scripts attempts to use the password with a certificate it already has to access a website that requires authentication.